# How to make wpa_supplicant automatically log into file

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wpa

I am trying to troubleshoot a wireless connection on FreeBSD.

I am manually editing the `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file

So far the `wpa_cli` status only tells me that it's Unauthorized.

I'd like to get a more verbose message and log the messages into a file for each wireless adapter.

1. How do I make wpa_supplicant automatically log into a file?
2. How do I make wpa_supplicant automatically change his debug level after a reconfigure?

Answer (score 1):

To get log into file for multiple WLAN interface you would have to run one wpa_supplicant instance per WLAN interface with -f and -d options. This way you'll get one log file per interface. I don't think, that wpa_supplicant would automatically change its verbosity level after connection. You could submit such a feature request.

Another way to troubleshoot your problem i.e. to get connection info, would be [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/). See [API](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html) description.

Comment: Yes I know I can use -f and -d, but I want it to be automatically set when the service starts ... /etc/rc.conf ?

Comment: Looks like you can set a variable as such wpa_supplicant_wlan0="-Dwext -dd -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log" but I don't know where to set this variable in FreeBSD

Comment: Have you looked in `/etc/rc.d`? I don't have experience with FreeBSD, but according to http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/rc-scripting/, the needed scripts reside there.